# How does numpy.linalg.inv calculate the inverse of an orthogonal matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I'm implementing a `LinearTransformation` class, which inherits from `numpy.matrix` and uses `numpy.matrix.I` to calculate the inverse of the transformation matrix.

Does anyone know whether numpy checks for orthogonality of the matrix before trying to calculate the inverse? I ask because most of my matrices (but not all) will be orthogonal and I wondered whether to implement some quick orthogonality check before trying to invert.

Comment: You can look at the source: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.7.0/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L404

Comment: Aye, I tried that, but I think the function just calls a wrapped C function. I could dig around in that, but I figured that somebody on here might just know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It does not!

`numpy.linalg.inv(A)` actually calls `numpy.linalg.solve(A,I)`, where `I` is the identity, and solve uses [lapack's LU factorization](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgesv.f).

That is, eventually, it does Gaussian elimination where orthogonality isn't detected by default.

And I don't think there is a shot into the dark to check something like `A * A.T = I` as matrix times matrix is costly.

Comment: Thanks for that, in this case, I'll add an orthogonal property to my class to speed things up a bit.

Comment: so if I know the matrix is Hermitian I can use cholesky  decomposition instead then use `linalg.cho_solve(C,I)`?