# Matrix inversion speed in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have been reading the book "Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow". In Chapter 4 (page 110), it says: *The computational complexity of inverting such a matrix is typically about O(n^2.4) to O(n^3) (depending on the implementation). In
other words, if you double the number of features, you multiply the computation time by roughly 2^2.4 = 5.3 to 2^3 = 8.*

I tested the above in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
nsize = 100
A = np.random.rand(nsize, nsize)
x = np.random.rand(nsize, 1)
b = A.dot(x)
# np.linalg.inv(A) or np.linalg.inv(A).dot(b) - not a big difference in time
timeit.timeit('np.linalg.inv(A)','import numpy as np\nfrom __main__ import A, b', number=10000)
```

I get about 2.5 seconds for `nsize=100` and get about 8.5 seconds for `nsize=200`. The compute cost seems to increase a factor of 3.4 (8.5/2.5) which is well below the range mentioned by the author. Can someone explain what causes this "speedup" ?

P.S: I tested the code with `nsize` of 5000 and 10000. The compute times were 3.2 and 25 seconds respectively - implying a 7.8 fold increase in time compared to 3.4 for the smaller `nsize` in the original question. Is this due to cache effects?

Comment: 2.5 seconds for *one* inversion or for 10000?

Comment: for 10000 of course? https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#cmdoption-timeit-n

Comment: Refer these two questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569613/how-does-numpy-linalg-inv-calculate-the-inverse-of-an-orthogonal-matrix             https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/38353/complexity-class-of-matrix-inversion

Comment: That's what I suspected, but you didn't make the connection between the code and the result entirely clear (that link is the wrong place, btw). And if it's for 10000, then that means a single inversion is super fast and you should instead measure with larger matrices (and fewer executions - I'd just do *one*).

Comment: @KellyBundy I tested the code with `nsize` of 5000 and 10000. The compute times were 3.2 and 25 seconds respectively - implying a 7.8 fold increase in time compared to 3.4 for the smaller `nsize` in the question. Is this due to cache effects?

Comment: Cache effects probably play a role as well, but I can't tell how much and in which direction. Maybe 100 and 200 both fit into the same cache level, but 5000 benefits from a cache that 10000 exceeds. Or maybe it's the other way around, 5000 and 10000 benefit equally much/little from caches but 100 benefits from the fastest cache level while 200 doesn't (or does, but less). The other effect is the actual algorithmic complexity. O(n^3) doesn't mean the time is proportional to n^3. It might be proportional to n^3 + 23n^2 + 42nlogn. And then the latter terms, while their impact disappears for ...

Comment: ... larger n, can be significant for small n and make it look more like O(n^2) complexity there. But to be honest I don't know how to distinguish how much of the factor comes from cache effects and how much from the algorithmic complexity.

Answer (score 3):

Numpy uses a LU factorization of LAPACK (as pointed out by @Murali in the comments). The LU factorization is usually done by OpenBLAS on most platforms (or the Intel MKL that behave similarly). OpenBLAS use `dgemm` calls (matrix multiplication) so to make the LU factorization faster. The `dgemm` is one of the most optimized BLAS primitive for large matrices. It make use of multiple threads and SIMD instructions so to be very fast. That being said, on small matrices, using **multiple threads introduce a significant overhead** (creating threads, distributing the work and waiting the results takes time). This overhead tends to be negligible for bigger matrices. The same thing is also true for SIMD instructions with even smaller matrices: SIMD instruction are fast for computing relatively large array but they have a high latency compared to scalar ones (that can be better pipelined for small matrices). Loop unrolling also cause the same effect (for very very small matrices) as well as CPU caches. On top of that Numpy does some type checks and internal work (so to optimize inner loops in some other cases) that takes few microseconds. The combination of all these factor cause the code to be very inefficient for small matrices and faster for bigger one. This overhead introduce a bias in the measured speed-up.

On my machine, for matrices of time 100, the `dgemm` calls take 19% of the time, `dtrsm` takes 11% and `dlaswp` takes 7% (and other calls takes a negligible time and the rest is lost in waits or in the kernel). For a matrix of size 200, `dgemm` calls take 29% and `dtrsm` 12%, `dlaswp` 7%. For a matrix of size 1000, `dgemm` calls take 57% and `dtrsm` 5%, `dlaswp` 6%. As we can see, most of the time is wasted on matrices of size 100 while most of the time is use by BLAS operation for matrices of size 1000.

Note the LU factorization is hard to parallelize. This is an active field of research (lasting since decades). Furthermore, the best parallelization methods (typically based on tasks) are unfortunately not used in libraries like OpenBLAS yet. AFAIK, the MKL use them a bit. State of the art implementation are faster, especially for small matrices since the `dgemm` is properly optimized for large matrices.

The multithreading can be disabled in OpenBLAS using `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`. With that, I got 151 µs for matrices of size 100 and 800 for matrice of size 200. One should consider the ~4 µs of Numpy overhead, and other overheads that are not constant like page faults, allocations, latency of SIMD instructions, cache effects, branch prediction, etc. That being said, the factor reach 5.44 (without the Numpy overheads). For 200 VS 400, it is 5.67. And for 400 VS 800, it is even 6.8. The main reason the factor is still not close to 8 (besides the other overheads) is that OpenBLAS is not optimized to run LU factorization with 1 threads: the internal parameters are set sub-optimaly and the algorithm is not optimal in this case.